# Mongo Views Count too slow

Tags: mongodb

I have one view in MongoDB and when I run a count it takes too much time. But when I do the count in the original collection it's fast.

ie:

```
db.productViewCollection.count()
```

super slow

```
db.productCollection.count()
```

is super fast

How can I make it fast as the original collection?

Comment: Try `countDocuments()`, probably you have indexed fields in the original collection. Try to index some fields in `productViewCollection` and then try to run it again.

Comment: Can you update your question with the definition of the view's pipeline?